# FileContentResult writes to response body

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, download

Why does this write "w,w,w" to the response instead of opening a save file dialog?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Export(int id)
    {            
        var contentType = "text/csv";
        var content = "w,w,w";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        var result = new FileContentResult(bytes, contentType)
                {
                    FileDownloadName = "www.csv"
                };
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can't put this in the question as a comment, How are you making the call to the controller?

Comment: Doh, I was using an ajax get!

Comment: Ahh, yeah that would cause problems. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a POST and not a GET.

Comment: It does the same thing when I GET it.